# Discrete Math Proof verification: products of floor

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Determine if the following is true or false and provide a proof:

$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\exists y\in\mathbb{R}$ so that $\lfloor xy\rfloor = \lfloor x\rfloor \lfloor y\rfloor$

My attempt:

-The statement is false, the negation is as follows:
$\exists x\in\mathbb{R}$, so that $\forall y\in\mathbb{R}$ $\lfloor xy\rfloor \neq \lfloor x\rfloor \lfloor y\rfloor$.

-Proof-

Let $x=10.99$ and suppose $y$ is an arbitrary but fixed real number. By the definition of floor, there exist unique integers $n$ and $m$, such that  $n=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $n\leq x < n+1$, and $m= \lfloor y\rfloor$ and $m \leq x < m+1$.

So,
   $10 = \lfloor 10.99\rfloor$ and $10 \leq 10.99 < 11$.

Now,
   $10y \leq 10.99y < 11y$
........(stuck..??)

---

So I understand that what I am trying to prove is that: $\lfloor xy\rfloor \neq \lfloor x\rfloor \lfloor y\rfloor$. However I am unsure of how to correctly choose(suppose) one equation, and manipulate it enough to prove that it doesn't equate to the other. I assume the issue is with the sentence "By the definition of floor, there exists unique integers $n$ and $m$, such that $n= \lfloor x\rfloor$ and $n \leq x < n+1$, and $m= \lfloor y\rfloor$ and $m \leq x < m+1$", and whatever follows thereafter.

I am trying to figure out how to complete the proof. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement you are trying to prove is true, so you are unable to disprove it.

**Hint**:

The statement says that for every $x$, there **exists** some $y$. So all you need to do is find some particular $y$ for which the equality holds.

Try to prove the statement by using very simple numbers for $y$....

Comment: One might even say that if you think about it right, there's nothing to it!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Well, that's *one* way of looking at it, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, you guys!!!

Comment: @5xum Then my attempt at a fully formatted proof is the following, are you able to follow it?:

Let $x$ be an arbitrary but fixed real number and let $y=1$. Then by the definition of floor,  $⌊1⌋= 1$, and:

$⌊x*y⌋ = ⌊x*1⌋ = ⌊x⌋$ (by arithmetic)....
and, $⌊x⌋*⌊1⌋ = [x]*1$ (by the definition of floor)....
 $⌊x⌋*1 = ⌊x⌋$ (by arithmetic)....
Thus, For all real numbers $x$, there exists a real number $y$ such that x$⌊x*y⌋ = ⌊x⌋⌊y⌋$ is true.

Comment: @SajSeesSound Looks good to me! Well done! (notice you could also use $y=0$ for an alternative proof).

Comment: @SajSeesSound Just keep the comment with the final proof - I'll also delete mine. You are wecome, I am happy to help. Don't worry, tasks like this one get very easy after some experience!